# Designer 2013 workflow with Visio professional missing stencils

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, visio

I have SP Designer 2013 and used it to create workflows for our 2013 on-prem hosted sites. So far so good.

I recently got Visio 2013 Professional installed and was excited to try the visual design view and to import/export to Visio. After the install I' restarted my machine and the **Visual Designer View** and **Export to Visio** are both enabled in the ribbon. But neither does anything.

I get a progress dialog that says "Generating workflow stencils/Checking if the workflow stencils are already generated" for a few seconds. The progress meter doesn't advance and then it goes away. The view doesn't change, nor does it export a file.

When trying to import I'm asked to name the new workflow, prompted to select the visio file, and then nothing. It doesn't create the workflow and it doesn't import the file.

I've googled on stencils and workflows. I only find MS propaganda about this cool new feature and nothing on it not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you setup the VISIO service in your SharePoint farm?

Answer (score 1):

Visio diagrams can be rendered by Visio Services and viewed in a Web browser. Visio Services lets users share and view Visio diagrams. So, you need to enable setup the service before the hand to use the VISIO diagrams from the SPD workflow.

[Overview of the VISIO Service in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663485.aspx)

Comment: How would I check this? And I need this even if I have the actual apps? I'm not using a web browser.

Comment: Go to Central Administration -> Application Management section, click Manage service applications. Here you should see "Visio Graphics Service" and "started" if it is already configured. I think you can`t see the Visio diagram from the SPD Designer workflow with out this service.

Comment: I don't have access to central admin. Just site collection admin.

Comment: You can see only with central admin access.

Comment: I checked with my IT department. Visio services are enabled and member of their team have been able to use the Visual Design view in SPD 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and I worked with it for 1 week. Finally the solution was the AMD and Intel chip different. If you have AMD chip architectural, You have to install the 64 bit version of Sharepoint Designer 2013 and SP1 and Visio Prof 2013 Sp1. Whithout that the SP1 the version will be different. You can check it in the Control Panel/Installed Software.
I hope it will be working on your system.

Regards,
Tibi